# Select list not getting populated (jQuery Ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

**Update:** Got this working by disabling CodeIgniter Profiler which was interfering with the Ajax success response.  I think it adds a div to the JSON response.

I am trying to populate a dependent select box with data from mysql database.  The problem is that the dependent select box is not getting populated in spite of getting data in the correct format in response to Ajax request.

Please help me as I am totally clueless about what's happening here. Below is my JavaScript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').change(function(){ 
        $("#cities > option").remove(); 

        var form_data = {
            country: $('#country').val(),
            csrf_token_name: $.cookie("csrf_cookie_name")
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/outlets/get_cities", 
            data: form_data,
            dataType : "JSON",
            success: function(cities)
            {
               $.each(cities,function(id,name)
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(id);
                    opt.text(name);
                    $('#cities').append(opt); 
                });
            }

        });

    });
});
</script>
```

And here is the HTML.  I am using Codeigniter.

```
<form id="form">
<?php $cities['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?>
<label for="country">Country: </label><?php echo form_dropdown('country_id', $countries, '#', 'id="country"'); ?><br />
<label for="city">City: </label><?php echo form_dropdown('city_id', $cities, '#', 'id="cities"'); ?><br />
</form>
```

Here is the controller:

```
function get_cities(){
    $country = $this->input->post('country');
  $this->load->model('city');
  header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
  echo (json_encode($this->city->get_cities($country)));
}
```

& the Model:

```
function get_cities($country = NULL){
  $this->db->select('id, name');

  if($country != NULL){
      $this->db->where('countries_id', $country);
  }
  $query = $this->db->get('cities');

  $cities = array();

  if($query->result()){
      foreach ($query->result() as $city) {
          $cities[$city->id] = $city->name;
      }
  return $cities;
  }else{
      return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: How have you verified that the response is correct? And what does your data look like? Impossible to tell if your loop is correct if you don't show us what's being looped,.

Comment: @am not i am: valid point.  I am going to add the controller and model code to the question.

Comment: Please add the rendered response instead. Much easier to read that way. You can log it to the console, and copy/paste it. `console.log(JSON.stringify(cities));`

Comment: Here is the response that I am getting back: {"1":"Delhi-NCR","2":"Bangalore","4":"Mumbai"}.

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(typeof cities);` in your `success` callback?

Comment: On doing console.log I get {"1":"Delhi-NCR","2":"Bangalore","4":"Mumbai"}

Comment: Then you didn't use `typeof`. Please use the code in my previous comment.

Comment: With `typeof` I am getting back "object  add (line 73)" three times.

Comment: I assume you must have put it inside the `$.each` loop. If you put this inside the `$.each` loop, do you get the expected values? `console.log(id, name);`

Comment: Yes, I have put it inside the each loop.  Now with `console.log(id, name);' I am getting the id and names of the cities like "1 Delhi-NCR" and so on.

Comment: In that case, it should be working. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kLb8Y/). Make sure you don't have any other code that may interfere somehow.

Comment: ...before the loop, do this `console.log("quantity:", $('#cities').length);` to make sure the `select` element is being found. You should get `"quantity: 1"`. Also, make sure you don't have more than one element with `id = "cities"`.

Comment: Checked your demo and it is working.  Not sure about what else may be interfering with it in my code.  Will check.  Anyway, thanks for your help and time!!

Comment: post an answer and accept it, if it's working. That's nice to different people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright everyone, I managed to get this working by disabling CodeIgniter Profiler.  Codeigniter profiler, that otherwise is a handy tool, breaks javascript on any page with Ajax.  If you can't do without profiler, use the solution provided on [Making CodeIgniter’s Profiler AJAX compatible](http://dragffy.com/blog/posts/making-codeigniters-profiler-ajax-compatible)

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax success callback to:

```
    success: function (cities) {
        for (var id in cities) {
            var opt = $('<option />');
            opt.val(id);
            opt.text(cities[id]);
            $('#cities').append(opt);
        }
    }
```

Because your ajax result is not a array but an json object.